# how to sweeten ng-packagr secondary entry point path when consuming

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

**Shared Component Setup**

I have a shared angular component, with as a secondary entry point a bunch of protractor utilities to make it easier to test from the consuming application. We don't do monorepo so the repository is dedicated only to that one particular shared component. We distribute that shared component through `npm` using git urls. Here's roughly the project structure:

```
-. (root folder)
 |-.dist
 | |- shared-component (distributables)
 |
 |-.projects
 | |
 | |-. shared-component (sources - library)
 | | |
 | | |-. e2e-utils
 | | | |- public_api.ts
 | | | |- package.json (2nd entry point)
 | | | |- ... (sources)
 | | |
 | | |-. src
 | | | |-. lib
 | | | | |- ... (sources)
 | | | |- public_api.ts
 | | |
 | | |- package.json (1st entry point)
 | |
 | |- test-harness (demo - application)
 |
 |- angular.json
 |- package.json
 |- tsconfig.json
```

in `angular.json`:

- `shared-component` is defined as a `library`
- `test-harness` is defined as an `application`

in `package.json`:

```
"files": [ "dist/shared-component" ],
"main": "dist/shared-component/bundles/shared-component.umd.js",
"module": "dist/shared-component/fesm5/shared-component.js",
"es2015": "dist/shared-component/fesm2015/shared-component.js",
"esm5": "dist/shared-component/esm5/shared-component.js",
"esm2015": "dist/shared-component/esm2015/shared-component.js",
"fesm5": "dist/shared-component/fesm5/shared-component.js",
"fesm2015": "dist/shared-component/fesm2015/shared-component.js",
"typings": "dist/shared-component/shared-component.d.ts",
"metadata": "dist/shared-component/shared-component.metadata.json",
```

in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"paths": {
  "shared-component": [
    "dist/shared-component"
  ],
  "shared-component/*": [
    "dist/shared-component/*"
  ]
}
```

**Consuming Application Setup**

in `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "shared-component": "git+<git-url>#<version>"
  ...
}
```

in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { SharedComponentModule } from 'shared-component';
```

in `some.e2e.test.ts`:

```
import { E2EUtils } from 'shared-component/dist/shared-component/e2e-utils'
```

**Question**

How do I shorten the above to a simple:

```
import { E2EUtils } from 'shared-component/e2e-utils'
```

**Wonky solution**

In the consuming application's `tsconfig.json` and *foreach* consumed shared-whatever:

```
"paths": {
  ...
  "shared-component/*": [
    "node_modules/shared-component/dist/shared-component/*"
  ],
  ...
},
```

I don't like that solution because it forces to add an extra entry *per consumed package* which is overhead. I'd like to believe there is a better solution out there (I've been wrong before).

**Literature**

- [angluar-cli library create secondary entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50802447/angluar-cli-library-create-secondary-entry-point) (similar-ish but not the same I believe, different project setup)
- https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/secondary-entrypoints.md
- https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/199 (not terribly relevant but could be a source of inspiration)

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution for this?

Comment: That's what we settled for but I haven't looked back into it since then.